# Git permission fix does not make changes for commit?

Tags: git

I did the following:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x build_detect_platform
```

But after do this, when I try to git commit, it says nothing to commit. Why and how to make that file's permission correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if your `build_detect_platform` already has the `+x` flag ?

Try setting `-x` instead :

```
git update-index --chmod=-x build_detect_platform
git status
```

if you see a difference staged in the index, this means the file is actually already marked as executable in your repo.

(note : to revert this action : `git reset build_detect_platform`)

Comment: Thanks, so I did [ -x ], says Changes to be commited: (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage) modified : build_detect_platform, so this means I didn't need to do +x.